# For Spatialite databases in QGIS, why is the provider 'spatialite' sometimes and 'ogr' other times?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, ogr, spatialite, data-source

I have many spatialite databases that I use across a lot of projects and sometimes the Provider is set to 'spatialite' and sometimes it's set to 'ogr', seemingly arbitrarily.

This causes issues when updating datasources for broken links etc.

Why does this happen and is there a way to force it to be consistent?

Comment: I have noticed this sometimes depends on how the spatialite file was loaded - drag and drop vs via the file browser vs via Add Spatialite Layer ... I've run into this issue before as well

Answer (score 2):

I was looking into [something related](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427609/in-qgis-how-do-the-providers-spatialite-and-ogr-influence-loading-editing-a) and as she_weeds mentioned, there seems to be a way to force the chosen provider:

- ogr: Loading via *Vector* (Data Source Manager) or drag & drop
- spatialite: Loading via *SpatiaLite* (Data Source Manager) or DB Manager

Once loaded the provider can even be changed with the plugin '[Change Datasource](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/changeDataSource/)' while the project is open.
Unfortunately I coulnd`t find out, how the providers influences working with the layers performance-wise.