# In QGIS how do the providers 'spatialite' and 'ogr' influence loading, editing and processing sqlite/spatialite layers?

Tags: qgis, ogr, performance, spatialite, data-source

Referencing [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353182/for-spatialite-databases-in-qgis-why-is-the-provider-spatialite-sometimes-and) older post it seems to me, that indeed the provider is dependent on how the file was loaded: 
-> ogr: Loading via Vector (Data Source Manager) *or* drag & drop
-> spatialite: Loading via SpatiaLite (Data Source Manager) *or* DB Manager

Once loaded the provider can even be changed with the plugin ['Change Datasource'](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/changeDataSource/) while the project is open.
Still the provider seems to have an impact on things like available field types and most important performance:
Whereas Geoprocessing Tools are much faster with the spatialite provider, calculating fields seems to take considerably longer.
Are there any other up-/downsides to using either the native or ogr provider?